# Initialize aggregate member in generic template code

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, language-lawyer, aggregate-initialization

For example,

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct node {
  T data;
  node* pnext;
};

template <typename T, typename... Us>
void func(Us&&... args) {
  // Initialize a node<T> with data initialized from args...
}
```

Ways I can think of and their limitations.

1. `node<T> v{ T(forward<Us>(args)...) }`. This involves [copy-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) which fails to work if `T` is non-copyable and non-movable, e.g., an [atomic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/atomic) type.
2. `node<T> v{ {forward<Us>(args)...} }`. This involves [copy-list-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) which fails to work if the selected constructor is explicit. For example, `node<unique_ptr<int>> n{ {new int()} }` doesn't work.

I guess the question is solved if I can somehow direct-initialize (e.g., direct-list-initialization) the aggregate member. Yet I don't find how that is possible other than coding a user-provided constructor, making `node` a non-aggregate type, which is overkill and I'm reluctant to do so. Any idea?

Comment: `node<T> v{ T(forward<Us>(args)...) }` does not fail even if `T` is non-copyable and non-movable because of guaranteed copy elision.

Comment: Having the c++ tag is pretty important for visibility, and since templates implies generic programming, I've edited it out. Hope this doesn't conflict with your intention

Comment: `node<T> v{ {forward<Us>(args)...} }` __is__ direct list initialization

Comment: @PasserBy: Direct initialization of `node<T>`. But the inner braced-init-list initializes the first member of `node<T>` via copy-list-initialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++14 has no effective solution to this dilemma. Well, not while still using aggregate initialization. If you give `node<T>` a variadic constructor, then it can forward the parameters directly to the member initializer:

```
template <typename T>
struct node {
  T data;
  node* pnext;

  template<typename ...Args>
  node(Args ...&&args) : data(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
};
```

Thus allowing you to invoke `node<T> v( T(forward<Us>(args)...) )`. Of course, it's not an aggregate anymore.

C++17's rules of guaranteed elision allow `node<T> v{ T(forward<Us>(args)...) }` to not provoke a copy or move.